# How can I create some sort of policy for a pull request to be rejected if there are x amount of bug items in the back log

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to find a way to reject a pull request into my master branch if there are still bug work items open in my back log in azure devops. I know I can create pre-deployment gates in the release pipeline to prevent release but I want to stop the build pipeline under that condition. to be more specific im trying to make sure my pull request to start my build to be later be released doesn't contain a critical bug in the back log items

Comment: Be careful — this policy says No Bugfixes will be released until All bugs are fixed. You can't fix and release that _One_ critical bug if there any other bugs.

Comment: I gotcha, to be more specific im trying to make sure my pull request to start my build to be later be released doesn't contain a critical bug in the back log items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I create some sort of policy for a pull request to be rejected if there are x amount of bug items in the back log

AFAIK, there is no such out of box way to do this.

To receive this, you could create a **Build validation** on the master branch:

`Branches`->`master`->`Branch policies`->`Build validation`

Then, create a build pipeline with **Agentless** job:

[image]

and select **Shared Queries**, set the **Upper threshold** for the Query work items task:

[image]

Now, we just need to create a Shared Query to get the all the open bug work items:

[image]

Hope this helps.